# No 3.5mm jack shown under playback devices

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, hdmi, speakers

I'm trying to repair my friends sound problem in Windows 7. The computer is a HP Media Center PC with `Asus M2N68-LA` motherboard and onboard audio. I've set up the drivers and the sound card is shown in Device Manager. When I go to `Control Panel` and `Audio`, I don't see the 3.5mm jack shown in playback devices.

I have tried to upgrade the drivers, checking audio is enabled in BIOS etc.

The computer has two front speaker outputs, one in the back and one in the front. Neither of them work or a listed under playback devices. There is only two High Definition Audio devices listed and labeled as HDMI. When trying to play audio, the bars are presenting the current audio output (the green bars).

What could be wrong

Comment: Just curious, did you get the drivers from HP?

Answer (score 1):

Did you already do this diagnostic?

1 open control panel

2 in the search box type "audio"

3 under troubleshooting click "Find and Fix audio playback problems"

4 in the "playing audio" pop-up window click next

[image: did you try this?]

Comment: Instead of just putting numbers on a picture, I would suggest describing what those steps are, even if they are brief.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that but it didn't manage to solve the problem.