# 3.5mm jack not shown under playback devices

Tags: audio, drivers, audio-output

Same problem as 
[No 3.5mm jack shown under playback devices](https://superuser.com/questions/589801/no-3-5mm-jack-shown-under-playback-devices)
The computer is running windows 8, I have attempted to run the audio output diagnostic, with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the correct Sound driver? Also, if you go to device manager (right click on Computer > manage), does the device appear to be in working order? I had a problem very similar to yours on a Windows 8.1 PC, and it appeared the driver was outdated. Latest sound driver solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the audio jack your are trying to input in could be defected inside.If it is working perfectly in windows 7 then you should try to install windows 8 again and check it again as some drivers would have been left during the installation.

If this doesn't help then try downloading latest drivers for your device.